# AWS routing all outbound traffic through a NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

Im in need of some general advise re aws VPCs and routing. My basic scenario is that I have a few app servers in an ASG behind an ELB. These app servers make SOAP calls to a provider that ip whitelists so I need to make outgoing requests coming from a fixed IP.

What I have attempted to do is create a private (no internet gateway) VPC and add my app instances here. Then Ive created a public VPC (internet gateway here) and placed my ELB and NAT instances.

If the routing/security is setup correctly would this setup make sense?

Comment: You'll need to assign Elastic IP(s) to your NAT machine(s) to ensure they have consistent IP addresses.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, though your wording is a bit off. Hopefully you created a public subnet and a private subnet. You put your ELB and your NAT in the public subnet, and your app servers/ASG in the private subnet. You set your route table for the private subnet to send outbound traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 through the NAT.

As @brian-knight states in the comment, you should allocate an Elastic IP and assign it to your NAT. This way if your NAT changes (e.g. the instance fails and must be replaced or something) you can reassign the EIP to a replacement NAT and not have to have the whitelist updated.